# 'to_csv' returning error has no attribute

Tags: python, csv, attributeerror

I'm trying to download filtered geojson data i've downloaded from simplemaps.com into a CSV file from google colab. However I keep getting an attribute error:'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. Code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
list_of_geocoders=[]
for i in tqdm(all_cities):
  geo=geocoder.osm(i,maxRows=2) #maxRow =2 means it will pick first 2 results for each city, in case the first result is not of type = 'administrative'
  for g in geo:
    if g.json['type'] == 'administrative' :
      if g.json['address'] not in list_of_geocoders: #avoid repetition
        list_of_geocoders.append(g.json['address'])

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/outpur.csv'

with open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
  list_of_geocoders.to_csv(f)
```

Comment: `to_csv()` is a pandas dataframe method. `list_of_geocoders` is not a dataframe, it's a list of strings (that's what I'm assuming `g.json['address']` is).

Comment: You can use the `csv` module to write a CSV file by looping over a list. But if each element of the list is just a single string, just write them all to the file. There's nothing to separate with commas, so you don't need to use CSV-specific code.

Answer (score 1):

`to_csv()` is for writing a pandas dataframe to a CSV fgile.

If you have a list of strings, just write each string to the file directly.

```
with open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
    for address in list_of_geocoders:
        f.write(f'{address}\n')
```